# Why does the output show "null"?

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.*;

public class TriangleType {
    int side1, side2, side3;  
    String kind;

    public TriangleType(int a, int b, int c) {
        side1 = a;
        side2 = b;
        side3 = c;

        if (a==b || b==c)
            kind = "Equilateral";
    }

    public static void main (String[]args)  {
        TriangleType triangle1 = new TriangleType(12, 13, 14);

        System.out.println("The sides are " + triangle1.side1 + " " +triangle1.side2 + " " +triangle1.side3);
        System.out.println("Triangle type: " + triangle1.kind );

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
The sides are 12 13 14
Triangle type: null
```

How can I make the triangle type output to show "equilateral"?

Comment: How about actually creating an equilateral triangle? (Also note that the condition for an equilateral triangle is incorrect...)

Comment: @Sweeper hahaha thanks for mentioning that It's just I'm soo tired already hahaha

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I'm sorry, but how? sorry I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your equilateral formula is wrong:

```
if (a==b || b==c)
kind = "Equilateral";
```

Should be

```
if (a==b && b==c)
kind = "Equilateral";
```

Second, the triangle you are creating needs equal sides to be equilateral

```
   TriangleType triangle1 = new TriangleType(12, 12, 12);
```

Also, IMO if the triangle is not equilateral, you should set it kind to something else ("not equilateral"?)

You also might want to think of getting rid of the `kind` member variable, as your equilateral function can be calculated when needed

Comment: ARGGHH  OMG I'm so dumb hahaha... THANK YOU SO MUCH to its just that I'm so tired already that I can't think straight

Comment: @SethJustinValenciano please remember to click on an answer to mark this as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that this triangle (12 13 14) is not equilateral. If you make it equilateral, say (a = b = c = 12), then the output of the triangle type will be "equilateral"

```
    public class TriangleType {


int side1, side2, side3;
String kind;


public TriangleType(int a, int b, int c) {

    side1 = a;
    side2 = b;
    side3 = c;

    if (a==b || b==c)
        kind = "Equilateral";

}


public static void main (String[]args)  {



    TriangleType triangle1 = new TriangleType(12, 12, 12);

    System.out.println("The sides are " + triangle1.side1 + " " +triangle1.side2 + " " +triangle1.side3);
    System.out.println("Triangle type: " + triangle1.kind );

    System.exit(0);

}
```

}

Comment: ARGGHH OMG I'm so dumb hahaha... THANK YOU SO MUCH to its just that I'm so tired already that I can't think straight

Answer (score -1):

Because no one of this condition in if-statement is not true. You are set a sides of triangle, but each of this side is not equal. Seems like you should  set default value for `kind`